# How to uninstall MS SQL ODBC driver 17 in unattended mode?

Tags: windows-installer

I try to install in unattended mode (chef-client) newest version of MS SQL ODBC driver. Log shows no error but old version is listed in Programs and features.

When I run msiexec interactively, installation procedure displays dialog that previous version of product is installed and it will be uninstalled. I cancel manual installation and try to run install and specify arguments `/Quiet` `/Passive`. It does not work.

My next try was to first uninstall previous version of ODBC driver. I fetch product Guid and run `msiexec /x "{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}" /Quiet /Passive /log logfile`. No error in log file but driver is not uninstalled.

When I run same command interactively from elevated command prompt, driver is uninstalled.
How to uninstall MS SQL ODBC driver 17 in unattended mode?

Comment: Is it possible that you have both the x64 and x86 versions installed at the same time.  Actually, I KNOW it is possible.. but could that be your problem?

Comment: 64 bit saetup installs both architectures.
Setup procedure installs 32 bit driver in syswow6432. We install 64 bit driver.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was files were locked. Ultimatelly I managed to get error message when uninstalling interactivelly. Message showed which processes should be stopped.
Unattended uninstallation does not print any error message. It silently continues and prints in log that everything went fine.
I consider this as a bug in product install/uninstall procedure.